# Permission Denial with ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY

Tags: android

A user has reported the following Force Close:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.PICK_ACTIVITY cmp=com.android.settings/.ActivityPicker (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{43ab9d40 15868:com.barkside.music/u0a10113} (pid=15868, uid=10113) requires huawei.android.permission.HW_SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1434)
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1388)
>   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1985)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1419)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3449)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
>   at com.barkside.music.PlayInActivity.onAddApp(Unknown Source)

This occurs when I attempt to startActivity using the [ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY) .

The only report I have for this is for Huawei Ascend Mate 2 running 4.3.

So Huawei seem to have locked down this for use by System apps only.  Is there anyway round this *without* having to implement my own pick activity listing installed apps to pick from?

Edit: Added code:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Pick App to Play in");
pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);
this.startActivityForResult(pickIntent, REQUEST_PICK_APPLICATION);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `Intent.createChooser()`? Or is that how you got this in the first place? You might want to post your code that is triggering the stack trace.

Comment: Note that I am not saying that your attempt to use `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY` should fail; I just [filed a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=133419) regarding your crash. However, I don't see many developers using that action directly. The chooser model seems to be more common, and it is possible that Huawei did not mess around with the chooser (and if they did, that would be a bigger problem). I'm just trying to determine the use case for `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`, as that can help us help you find an alternative.

Comment: @CommonsWare To be honest, I didn't know ACTION_CHOOSER could be used for this activity chooser feature of mine. But you are right, it would solve my problem. Slightly embarrassed now! Shall I remove the question, answer it, or do you want to answer it?

Comment: What I would recommend that you do is get something working with the chooser, then write up an answer showing your old code and the new code, to document your workaround. Your question is perfectly valid (if unfortunate, as Huawei shouldn't be doing this...), so it would be better to document the workaround.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks @CommonsWare and thanks for filing the bug report!

Comment: @CommonsWare So I tried the createChooser, and of course it actually sent the intent to the application chosen by the user.  What I wanted is for the class of the activity to be returned to me in onActivityResult.  Can ACTION_CHOOSER do this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I tried the createChooser, and of course it actually sent the intent to the application chosen by the user. What I wanted is for the class of the activity to be returned to me in onActivityResult. Can ACTION_CHOOSER do this somehow?

No. For that, particularly given your problems with `ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`, you are going to have to roll your own UI, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. It's reminiscent of writing a home screen launcher, as in [my Launchalot sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot).